# ADFS 4.0 Authentication is not working in Internet Explorer Standard Session but works through InPrivate Session of Internet Explorer

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, proxy, authentication, internet-explorer-11

Environment: ADFS 4.0, Windows Server 2016, Windows 10, Bizagi, Forms Authentication, SAML 2.0

We recently integrated ADFS with Bizagi which uses SAML 2.0 for exchanging data for authenticating the users of Active Directory.

1. We are getting saml2_error while authenticating the user in Windows 10 Internet Explorer while it is working fine in Windows 10 Chrome and In Private session of Internet Explorer.
2. I have used fiddler to dig into saml responses, strangely, when we use the fiddler to capture the traffic, the authentication working absolutely fine as fiddler changes internet explorer settings to use the proxy server and fiddler listens at 8888 port.

Am not sure what is happening at all, can anybody help me?